# Swift 3.0 : Ambiguous reference to member 'Subscript' issue in push notification

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

This is the following code but i am getting this following error in swift3

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    notificationReceived(notification: userInfo as [NSObject : AnyObject])
}

func notificationReceived(notification: [NSObject:AnyObject]) {
        let viewController = window?.rootViewController
        let view = viewController as? ViewController
        view?.addNotification(
            title: getAlert(notification: notification).0,
            body: getAlert(notification: notification).1)
    }

    private func getAlert(notification: [NSObject:AnyObject]) -> (String, String) {
        let aps = notification["aps"] as? NSDictionary
        let alert = aps?["alert"] as? [String:AnyObject]
        let title = alert?["title"] as? String
        let body = alert?["body"] as? String
        return (title ?? "-", body ?? "-")
    }
```

But i am getting the following error "**Swift 3.0 : Ambiguous reference to member 'Subscript' issue**" at "**let aps = notification["aps"] as? NSDictionary**"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**type converson**

[image]

Change userInfo from NSDictionary to [String : Any]. and try once

```
let aps = notification["aps"] as? [String : Any]
```

or write as like

```
let aps = notification["aps" as NSString] as? [String:Any]
```

Answer (score 3):

String is not convertable to `NSObject`, just rename all your `[NSObject:AnyObject]` to `[String:Any]` with Swift 3